# BETWEEN Operator mySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

All,

Not sure why I am getting the error whilst running the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(R.id) AS total 
                    FROM request as R 
                    INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.uin = R.engineer_uin 
                    WHERE U.gm = 'BVG1'
                    AND R.date_received BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(R.date_received,'%d %m %Y')='01 04 2014' AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %m %Y')
```

`R.date_received` is in the following format: `2015-06-01 14:38:46`
I simply want to get the result between Now() and the previous year. (In the UK, we have financial year between april to next year april.

The error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='01 04 2014' AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %m %Y')
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is unwilling to read. The error message literally tells you what to fix.

Comment: _Any ideas?_ Yes actually, `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AND` clause you're looking for should look as follows:

```
...
AND R.date_received BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01,04,2014','%d,%m,%Y') AND NOW()
```

Comment: Thanks @uri2x This resolved the issue `SELECT COUNT(R.id) AS total FROM request as R INNER JOIN users AS U ON U.uin = R.engineer_uin WHERE U.gm = 'BVG1' AND R.date_received BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-04-2014','%d-%m-%Y') AND NOW()`